# ScalaTest Eclipse Plugin saying ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, scalatest

I have a ScalaTest test, and I'm trying to run it through Eclipse by right clicking and clicking `run as > ScalaTest File`  but Eclipse tells me

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1
    at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more`

I don't know what to make of this.

I'm using the Scala IDE build of Eclipse
Build id: 3.0.4-2.11-20140723-2253-Typesafe
Version 4.3.0

I'm using Scala version 2.11.1
ScalaTest version 2.11-2.1.6

I got Scala and ScalaTest through the Typesafe Activator program and generated the Eclipse project definition from their webapp. The ScalaTest plugin comes from the Scala IDE website.

Comment: It has something to do with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432509/scalatest-in-eclipse-running-it-gives-nullpointer-exception When I removed the scala jar (the one from the .ivy path that was added for me using the typesafe activator), Eclipse told me it could no longer detect a scala compiler and asked if I'd like to add one. I said yes and it added the one that comes with Scala IDE. Then scalatest started to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received this exception in the `4.1.1-vfinal-20150727-1320-Typesafe` build of the `Scala IDE Eclipse 4.3.0`. It was caused by the project's lack of a Scala Library, despite the fact that I created my project as a Scala Project. I had to manually add the scala library by right-clicking and choosing `Add Scala Library to Build Path`

Before adding the library it looked like this:

[image]

After adding the library, and running a ScalaTest test, it looks like this:

[image]

One might guess that the `Scala Library` would be added automatically when a Project with a `Scala Nature` is created using the `Scala Project Wizard` -- at least I did. But, this does not appear to be the case. If this was a design choice, it may have been made, because the `Scala Library` was often specified as a dependency of the project and the one added by the IDE was of a different version causing surprising behavior as well as IDE warnings to that effect. If that was the rationale, the Wizard should prompt the user to decide and perhaps provide an intelligent recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **sbt**? You may get this error when using "sbt eclipse". Solution is to **upgrade sbteclipse** plugin. It works in recent versions (definitely in 4.0.0).

The problem with the old version of the plugin is that it does not generate "org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER" into .classpath file.

Comment: I have the same problem, and "org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER" does appear in my classpath. It was generated by sbteclipse 3.0.0 as version 4.0.0 throws an exception